# Extract images from PDF with iTextSharp using Jscript

Tags: image, itext, jscript

I've seen a few posts on extracting images from PDF using iTextSharp, but all are VB/C# based.

A core part of these solutions is something like:

```
PdfDictionary res = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dict.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)));
PdfDictionary xobj = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT)));

if (xobj != null)
{
    foreach (PdfName name in xobj.Keys)
```

I can create the res and xobj objects fine in Jscript, but JScript does not support foreach loops. I have to do something like

```
for

 (var x = 0; x < xobj.Keys.Count; x++)
    {
        var name = xobj.Keys(x)
        ...
    }
```

But this is of course invalid.

Can someone explain how I can parse all the keys in xobj, without using foreach loops?

Comment: I'm no expert in JScript, but shouldn't it be `var name = xobj.Keys[x]` to access an element by its index?

Comment: Can't you use `for...in`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z08sst3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Alexis - My understanding is that Dictionaries aren't indexed - hence this produces compilation errors

Comment: Chris - SPOT ON :) Thanks :) Took a while to get the syntax 100% but I got there eventually! Thanks :)